# Comparing a list of strings with another list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

```py
positive_list = [line.strip() for line in open('positive-words.txt')] #converts text file to list
target_list = ['title', 'trump', 'impeached', 'for', 'abuse', 'of', 'power', 'two', 'weeks', 'before']

def wordcount(target_list, target_string):
    counter = 0
    for string in target_list:
        if string == target_string:
            counter += 1
        else:
            print('No matches found')
            break
    print('Number of matches: ' + counter)
wordcount(target_list, positive_list[x])
```

I was able to search the target_list with a string object but was unable to loop through the entire strings contained in the list positive_list.

Is there a way to loop through target_list with positive_list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set` for finding the matches:

```
target_set = set(target_list)
pos_set = set(positive_list)

matches = pos_set.intersection(target_set)
wordcount = len(matches)
```